# Generating graphs for results from hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, graph, jfreechart

I am trying to generate piechart for results from hadoop using JFreeChart. This is the code I am trying to run. The ouput  file is hdfs inside directory `"/MSN/result/part-r-00000"`.

```
public class PieChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame 
{
public PieChart_AWT( String title ) 
{
    super( title ); 
    setContentPane(createDemoPanel( ));
}
private static PieDataset createDataset( ) 
{
    // The name of the file to open.
    String fileName = "hdfs://localhost:9000/MSN/result/part-r-00000";

    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset( );

    try {Configuration conf=new Configuration( );
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
    FileSystem fs1 = FileSystem.get(conf);

    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            fs1.open(new Path(fileName))));
    // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.




    while((line = br1.readLine()) != null) {    
        String data[]=line.split(",");
        dataset.setValue( data[0], Double.parseDouble(data[1])); 


    }   

    // Always close files.
    br1.close();         
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                        fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                        + fileName + "'");                  
        // Or we could just do this: 
        // ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    return dataset;         
}
private static JFreeChart createChart( PieDataset dataset )
{
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(      
            "Mobile Salesxdass",  // chart title 
            dataset,        // data    
            true,           // include legend   
            true, 
            false);

    return chart;
}
public static JPanel createDemoPanel( )
{
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset( ) );  
    return new ChartPanel( chart ); 
}
public static void main( String[ ] args )
{
    PieChart_AWT demo = new PieChart_AWT( "Mobile Sales" );  
    demo.setSize( 560 , 367 );    
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( demo );    
    demo.setVisible( true ); 
}
}
```

This code is not working. Is there any changes to be made to the code?
If possible, please suggest some alternative methods to generate graphs for results in hadoop? The error which i am getting here is this:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: What's not working? How far does the code get? File? Dataset? Chart?

Comment: I have edited the code in the question  The error I am getting is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService;

Comment: Please edit your question to show the error and stack trace.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of the error message

Comment: NSME usually happens during the dependencies version missmatch. How do you manage yours dependencies?